# Почему не работает проверка на тип функции?

Tags: javascript, функции

возник вопрос, при выполнении кода

```
var arr = ['Hello', 'Name', 'lastName']
function isAllTrue(array, fn) {
  if (arr.length == 0 || !Array.isArray(arr)) {
    console.log('empty array')
  } else if (typeof fn != 'function') {
    console.log('fn is not a function')
  } else if (ft != false) {
    console.log(true)
  } else {
    console.log(false)
  }
  }
var ft;
function func(array) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof arr[i] == 'string') {
      ft = true;
    } else {
      ft = false;
    }
  }
}

func(array)

isAllTrue(array, func())
```

Не работает проверка fn на функцию, он в любом случае выдает, что Fn это не функция

```
else if (typeof fn != 'function') {
    console.log('fn is not a function')
  }
```

Comment: А зачем там ()?

Comment: Из-за этого и не работала, заметил. Спасибо.